# How can I update this vote counter dynamically with Ajax/JavaScript (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I built a simple voting system:

**votes_controller.rb:**

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def vote_up
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @vote = @post.votes.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :polarity => 1)
  end
end
```

(If there is any bad practice here, please let me know)

**views/show.html.erb:**

```
<h3><%= @post.votes.count %> votes</h3><br />

<%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_up_path(@post), :remote => true %>
```

(I will put this in a partial of course)

**routes.rb:**

```
get 'votes/:id/vote_up' => 'votes#vote_up', as: 'vote_up'
```

When I click the "Vote Up" link the vote is added to the post but I have to refresh the page in order to see the changes. How can I refresh `@post.votes.count` and `vote.user.username` dynamically with Ajax/JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First put make a wrapper div for show.html.erb

```
<div class='post-<%=@post.id%>' >
 <h3><%= @post.votes.count %> votes</h3><br />
 <%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_up_path(@post), :remote => true %>
</div>
```

and in vote_up.js.erb

```
$("post-<%=@post.id%>").html('<%=escape_javascript @post.votes.count %>');
```

or something like this