# Voting without refreshing the page and incrementing the score on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The other solutions here have not worked so far.  I have stories that I want users to vote on, with the voting being handled by the controller.

```
  def vote
    story = Story.find(params[:id])
    if current_user
      vote = story.votes.find_or_initialize_by(user: current_user)
      vote.change_vote!(params[:vote_value].to_i)
      redirect_to stories_path
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
```

change_vote! acts as a toggle, incrementing score based on the vote itself and whether or not it existed previously.  Works well.

view partial for votes:

```
<div class="story-votes">
  <div class="vote-container">
    <% if current_user && current_user.voted_on?(story) == 1 %>
      <%= link_to "UP", story_vote_path(story, 1), method: :put %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "up", story_vote_path(story, 1), method: :put %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="vote-count"><%= story.score %></div>
    <% if current_user && current_user.voted_on?(story) == -1 %>
      <span class="vote-down">
        <%= link_to "DOWN", story_vote_path(story, -1), method: :put %>
      </span>
    <% else %>
      <span class="vote-down">
        <%= link_to "down", story_vote_path(story, -1), method: :put %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You tagged this with `javascript` and `jQuery` which is what you need but have shown no examples of trying to use them. What you need to do is have those links make an ajax request and process the response with jQuery but showing that you tried is usually a good place to start.

Comment: I followed the example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148788/how-can-i-update-this-vote-counter-dynamically-with-ajax-javascript-rails), but I don't know how the vote_ip.js.erb would get invoked.

Comment: This is the view for your controller action. I personally do not like to use `js.erb` files but instead return the needed values as a `Json Object` and then parse that and apply appropriately.